# Is there any way of calculating the area between two "graphs" in Python?

Tags: python

[image: here]

You can see a part of plot I am given. It puts certain values (1 per second) into a line chart. My task is to calculate the white area between the lower red line and the green graph (in case the green values are less than the constant value of the red line). My first idea was to use integrals and I've been trying to do so for a good amount of time but I just can't make it, since I don't know how to get mathematical functions to describe the red and green graphs. Also I am quite new to python so it's even harder.
I am getting the green data points per cURL request in real time into my python script by the way, so that's not the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please, provide code you already wrote

Comment: An integral is just the sum of the function over infinitely small increments, your increments are 1 second so no need for the extra math. If you have two points on a graph how would you find the area between them and the axis? Solve that and add them up.

Comment: @Herlock there isn't really any code I could provide here. All I did was get said data into a dataframe consisiting of two columns (timestamp, value). My question is more about finding an appraoch.

Comment: @AmosBaker yeah I also kinda thought about it like that. You just supported my idea and I think I will stick to it.  Thank you!

Comment: This is a numerical integration problem. The most popular technique is the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). You'll have to add some extra code to handle the regions where the green parts are above the red line.